# Ext JS filtering rendered columns

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to be able to filter on each column of my data. Each time I filter, I use:

```
addFilter({

             dataIndex: 0, //Or 1,2.. depending on the column i want to filter on
             type: 'string', 
             value: value,
});
```

The problem here is that dataIndex of the column i am filtering on is an Object, so i am essentially filtering on the literal String value of 'Object'. It is Object because in my store, I am storing an Object for each dataIndex, and displaying it with a `render` function.

Click the header trigger menu, there is a text box i made to type for filter, if you enter any of the letters of the word 'Object', it works. How do I get it to filter the Object's value, not the literal string '`Object`'

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/163s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `type: 'string'` actually says that the filter shall work on a string. So the object is stringified into `[object object]` and compared to the value you provided.

Instead, you need to use a custom filter function. It would be useful to use an id on your filter, so new versions on the same column replace the old one.

```
var dataIndex = column.dataIndex,
    value = textfield.getValue();
grid.getStore().addFilter([{
    id:"filter-"+dataIndex,
    filterFn:function(record) {
        // Example: Only return records where the object has a property by that name.
        return Ext.Object.getKeys(record.get(dataIndex)).indexOf(value)>-1;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I have a question about this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1650  if you typed "bar" it shows the right rows, but if you delete the latters 'ar', it's back to 'b', but bammy doesnt show up anymore? is it because old filter didnt get removed?

Comment: In line 83, add `console.log(Ext.getCmp('myGrid').lockedGrid.getStore().getFilters().getRange());` and see for yourself... this is why I always provide an id to a filter. No two filters with same id on a store - the new one will overwrite the old one.

Comment: @Alexander How can this filter be applied when applying a renderer for a column and using the filter from GridFilters ?(http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.grid.filters.Filters.html)

Comment: @user6123723 Details are out of scope for a comment, but the idea is to derive a new class from one of the existing and override `constructor` and `createMenu`. If you have a specific example what you want to achieve, your question makes a good new question on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your menu change listeners

```
Ext.getCmp('myGrid').normalGrid.headerCt.getMenu().add({
xtype: 'textfield',
id: 'myT',
fieldLabel: 'Filter',
listeners: {
    change: function(field, value) {
        console.log([dataindexx, value]);

        Ext.getCmp('myGrid').normalGrid.getStore().filterBy(function(r) {

            if (!r.data[dataindexx].value.indexOf(value)) {
                return true
            };

        });


        if (value === '' || value === undefined) {
            Ext.getCmp('myGrid').normalGrid.getStore().filters.removeAll();
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks @LightNight, I wish i could accept both answers.